# AES encryption and decryption algorithm

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

Hi I am trying to write a simple java program for AES encryption and decryption.
I am doing this to encrypt a few columns for a csv.  So I am writing this program to begin with to get encryption and decryption right.  I am using keystorePass and keyPass.  I keep getting invalidkeyexception.  I've read about sun's security policy and that we can remove the restriction by overriding the security policy files.  But i am not sure if that is the problem.  I'd be more than happy to learn where the mistake is in this code. I am also not able to figure out the mistake in the decrypt method. Thanks a lot in advance.

This is how i run this program:   `java cipher.CipherUtils -encrypt abcd`

```
public class CipherUtils
{
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            String keystorePass="somekeystore";
            String keyPass="bigdata";
            String alias= "aes";

            InputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/myname/eclipse_workspace/cipher-project/cipher/aes.jck");  

            System.out.println("ENCRYPTION 01 - keystoreStream."); 

            KeyStore keystore=null;
            try {
                keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            try {
                keystore.load(keystoreStream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            try {
                if (!keystore.containsAlias(alias)) {  
                    throw new RuntimeException("Alias for key not found");  
                }
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            Key key=null;
            try {
                key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //can not pass byte arraye to config, need to encode it to string
       ;
            String keybase64= Base64.encodeBase64String(key.getEncoded());
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(keybase64), "AES");  

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            final String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));
            return encryptedString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

     public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
{
    try
    {
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        // Key key=null;
        String keystorePass="bellbigdata";
        String keyPass="bigdata";
        String alias= "hadoopaes";

        InputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/myname/eclipse_workspace/cipher-project/cipher/aes.jck");  

        KeyStore keystore=null;
        try {
            keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        try {
            keystore.load(keystoreStream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        try {
            if (!keystore.containsAlias(alias)) {  
                throw new RuntimeException("Alias for key not found");  
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        Key key=null;
        try {
          key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());
          System.out.println(key);
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //can not pass byte arraye to config, need to encode it to string
   ;

        String keybase64= Base64.encodeBase64String(key.getEncoded());
        //System.out.println(keybase64);
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(keybase64), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)));
        return decryptedString;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
        Options options = new Options();
        Option help = new Option("help", "Display help");
        Option encrypt = new Option("encrypt", true, " - string to encrypt");
        Option decrypt = new Option("decrypt", true, " - string to decrypt");
        options.addOption(help);
        options.addOption(encrypt);
        options.addOption(decrypt);
        try
        {
            CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
            if (cmd.hasOption("encrypt"))
            {
                final String strToEncrypt = cmd.getOptionValue("encrypt");
                final String encryptedStr = CipherUtils.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());
                System.out.println("String to Encrypt : " + strToEncrypt);
                System.out.println("Encrypted : " + encryptedStr);
            }
            else if (cmd.hasOption("decrypt"))
            {
                final String strToDecrypt = cmd.getOptionValue("decrypt");
                final String decryptedStr = CipherUtils.decrypt(strToDecrypt.trim());
                System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);
                System.out.println("Decrypted : " + decryptedStr);
            }
            else
            {
                HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                formatter.printHelp("[-h] [-encrypt ]", options);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code where you write the keys to the keystore. How long are the keys? An InvalidKeyException, surprise, has something to do with the key. You should show what the key is.

Comment: I am not sure about that?  Would you be able to help me with a code snippet please? thank you.

Answer (score -3):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   
from Crypto.Cipher import AES    
import base64    
import os    
def decryption(encryptedString):    
    PADDING= '{'    
    decodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)      
    key = ''   
    Cipher = AES.new(key)   
    decoded = decodeAES(Cipher, encryptedString)   
    print decoded
```

[image]

Comment: How could this answer the question? It looks like random characters and a picture attached.